# mongoose: filter query object params

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When the search conditions are complex, I want to create a dynamic query object.

For example:

```
dbQueryObj = {
            $and: [{
                $or: [
                    { auth: req.query.auth },
                    { title: req.query.title }
                ],
                date: {
                    $gte: new Date(req.query.startDate),
                    $lt: new Date(req.query.endDate)
                }
            }]
        }
```

Some values may not be filled in, such as the `req.query.endDate` may be null, the search object will become similar to the following:

```
 cteatedDate: {
     $gte: 'Wed Apr 07 2021 00:00:00  GMT 0800',
     $lt: null // or Invalid Date, 'null', ..etc 
 }
```

`$lt: null`, this condition will affect the search results, and nothing will be found.
Or maybe the other params is null, like `req.query.auth` and `req.query.title`;

Is there any way to remove these empty values? When the object has only one dimension, you can delete the empty values through the loop, but when the object is full of complex conditions such as $and, $or, how to deal with it

Comment: For what value of `x` does `new Date(x)` produce `null`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like - only add values if they are available in `query`

```
if (req.query) {
    const query = req.query;

    const orQuery = [];

    if (query.auth) orQuery.push({ auth: query.auth })
    if (query.title) orQuery.push({ title: query.title })

    const dateQuery = {};

    if (query.startDate) dateQuery['$gte'] = new Date(query.startDate);
    if (query.endDate) dateQuery['$lt'] = new Date(query.endDate);

    const dbQueryObj = {
        $and: [{
            $or: orQuery,
            date: dateQuery
        }]
    };

}
```

also, you can add checks for `orQuery` `dateQuery` if they are not present don't add in the query